# Everytime I run ps, it returns the usual PID and CMD, but

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, ps

In every book I've read, it never returns like this:

```
PID CMD
2748 -bash
8114 awk
7900 -bash
```

Which is what my `ps` returns. Is that normal for the `-` to be in front of the `bash`? I've only ever seen `2290 bash`, never without the `-` in front of it. Trivial question, but I assume it isn't normal. Thank you, and sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: I remember reading that it means login shell, not sure

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

This means a login shell. Take a look at `man bash`:

```
A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.
```

If you run `cat /proc/2748/cmdline` you will see the hyphen there. This is where ps is getting it from.
`-f` will look at `/proc/[pid]/cmdline`, whereas by default it will look at `/proc/[pid]/comm`.

```
tom@riki:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9230 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 9429 pts/2    00:00:00 ps

tom@riki:~$ ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
tom       9230  9229  0 17:39 pts/2    00:00:00 -bash
tom       9427  9230  0 18:22 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -f

tom@riki:~$ cat /proc/9230/comm
bash

tom@riki:~$ cat /proc/9230/cmdline
-bash
```